# Does the MacBook Pro M2 2023 charge >100W (140W, FastCharge) via the USB-C ports?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, magsafe, charger, apple-silicon

On the M1 MacBook Pros charging via the USB-C ports if only up to 100W (USB PowerDevlivery 20V 5A)

Hwr, did they improve it on the MBP M2 2023, so you could also FastCharge (140W - USB PD 28V 5A) via one of the USB-C Ports? Or still just via MagSafe3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only FastCharge using MagSafe 3 at 140 W

Apple doesn't mention nor offer FastCharge only using USB-C port.
Here is a screenshot from Apple's Fast Charge informations :
[image]

See also this from Macworld https://www.macworld.com/article/819438/best-macbook-usb-c-charger.html

> On the 16-inch MacBook Pro, you can only fast-charge with Apple’s 140W USB-C Power Adapter paired with the USB-C to MagSafe 3 Cable. Apple, Anker and UGreen are the only companies to make a power adapter that supports the latest PD 3.1 standard that supports power output to up to 240W; other USB chargers have a practical maximum of 100W.

Answer (score 2):

The MacBook Pro M2 has two Thunderbolt/USB4.  USB4 *mandates* PD ([Power Delivery Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery)) which version 3.1 allows for charging up to 240W (48V x 5A).  However, to achieve this, you must have a specific USB4 PD cable which is specially marked as such.  The charger must also conform to the 3.1 PD spec for this to work.

So, in short, you can get both charging speeds from the USB4 port and from the MagSafe3 adapter.

Comment: A USB4 source/sink must include a USB PD controller. A USB source must provide a minimum of USB PD's 5 [V] 1.5 [A] = 7.5 [W], up from USB's typical 5 [V] 0.5 [A] = 2.5 [W] (USB PD's minimum). There is no requirement beyond this. [Wiki:USB4:Power Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB4). There is definitely not a requirement to provide the USB PD's maximum 20 [V] 3 [A] (standard) or USB PD's maximum 48 [V] 5 [A] (which requires augmented / non-standard cabling). [Wiki:USB Hardware:USB Power Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery) (see table).

Comment: This answer is incorrect. USB4 devices like the M2 pro are obviously not required to charge at 240W

Comment: @navin, you need to read more carefully.  I said **up to** 240W which is the spec.

Comment: Sure and you can save "up to" 99% at my Amazon shop. Your answer is worse than useless: It's actively misleading. The fact that a laptop's ports are USB4 has nothing to do with the charge speed. The OP is asking how fast a specific laptop model can charge